# R future multisession limiting number of cpus

Tags: r, parallel-processing, cpu-usage, r-future

I'm currently parallellising by using the future package as follows:

```
plan(multisession, gc = TRUE)
standardised_addresses1 <- future_lapply(1:20000, function(x) x*x)
```

The problem is that it uses all the CPUs on the server.
I would like to limit the number of CPUs used by setting a parameter like:
workers = 18

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `plan(multisession, gc = TRUE, workers = 18)`.